# Android - sending data from acra to a php script

Tags: php, android, mysql, acra

I've been using acra in some of my apps and sending the data to Google Docs spread sheets, but I would like to switch to sending data to a mysql setup I have running on a server where I feel  the data would be more secure. I can see how to send the data using the post method but I can't tell the naming conventions of the data so I can catch them with a php script.

Does anybody know what the variable names are or where I can look at them so I know what to look for in my php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the [**acra**](http://code.google.com/p/acra/) app is using POST methods, use PHP's [$_POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) predefined variable and `var_dump` to read the parameters passed in the post.

Another useful is [$_GET](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)... just in case

EDIT: Upon further inspection, [**acra**](http://code.google.com/p/acra/) [source suggests](http://code.google.com/p/acra/source/browse/trunk/acra/src/main/java/org/acra/sender/HttpPostSender.java) that the [ReportField.java](http://code.google.com/p/acra/source/browse/trunk/acra/src/main/java/org/acra/ReportField.java) enum values are converted to strings via a `Map` and used with POST params. I suggest investigating those fields as well.

Comment: Cool thanks for the help :) I never thought to use var_dump with $_POST.