# Acra post script

Tags: android, crash-reports, acra

Tried to use ACRA in my app, but I can't get the google drive or the email working (in google drive I don't know how to create the form from the template, email tells me there is no such email address even though I am sending from the same email address). I would rather get the google drive spreadsheet thing working or better yet - if there is a ready-to-use script for free web host that I can use to get the reports. Anyone knows of such a script?

EDIT: I need a php one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like ACRA uses a simple post. What language do you need it in? For asp.net:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StringBuilder err = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (string name in Request.Form)
        {
            err.AppendLine(name + ": " + Request.Form[name]);
        }

        TextWriter tw = null;
        try
        {
            tw = new StreamWriter("f:\\errorLogs\\error_" + DateTime.Now.Ticks + ".txt");
            tw.WriteLine(err.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
        finally
        {
            if(tw != null)
                tw.Close();
        }
    }
```

Since you are using a "free web host", the location probably isn't valid for you, but this should at least get you pointed in the right direction. There is [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9424346/android-sending-data-from-acra-to-a-php-script) which is similar to yours. Most free web hosts use php.

EDIT:

Here is a basic [PHP script](http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=136146) (Not tested, but seems OK to me. My PHP is a bit rusty):

```
<?php
$file = 'postData.txt';
$arr= $_POST;
$fp = fopen($file, 'w') or die('Could not open file!'); 
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    $toFile = "Key: $key; Value: $value \n";
    // write to file 
    fwrite($fp, "$toFile") or die('Could not write to file'); 
}
// close file 
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, indeed I need a php script and not ASP.NET, and I don't know how to write it so I ask if there are any ready-to-use roaming the network. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see it until now.